# How to communicate different integration services in IIB?

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I using IIB to make a ESB project with 2 integration services.
One for register account, and one for access database.
I can do with SOAPRequest node for Request and recieve Response.
But now i'm trying to using another way to communicate 2 services.
I know IIB have Label node, but it just work internal service, not for 2 different services.
So how can I communicate 2 service in IIB without SOAPRequest ( maybe Route node or something). Its like messages can go one by one service.
Tks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "msgflow" instead of integration services, and then you can put MQInput, JMSInput, HTTPInput and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only one message flow. The better way is to transform the flows and subflows in a shared a library keeping your Integration service intact.